# Neo4j Variable Length Path and Aggregate Query

Tags: variables, neo4j, cypher, aggregation

I'm trying to perform a aggregation query on a variable length path where the nodes I want to aggregate on are not in the original path, but instead are related to them. For example my path looks like

```
MATCH p = (:Visit)-[:NEXT*]->(:Visit)
RETURN p
```

but each (:Visit) node is related to a (:Destination)

```
(:Visit)-[:LOCATION]->(:Destination)
```

The aggregation I want is to count the common paths based on the id property of the Destination nodes not the Visits. I figured out a way to use a Union to combine many fixed length paths results

```
MATCH (d1:Destination)--(v1:Visit), (d2:Destination)--(v2:Visit)
WHERE (v1:Visit)-[:NEXT]->(v2:Visit)
RETURN [d1.id,d2.id] AS Path, count(*) AS PathCount
UNION
MATCH (d1:Destination)--(v1:Visit), (d2:Destination)--(v2:Visit), (d3:Destination)--(v3:Visit)
WHERE (v1:Visit)-[:NEXT]->(v2:Visit)-[:NEXT]->(v3:Visit)
RETURN [d1.id,d2.id,d3.id] AS Path, count(*) AS PathCount
UNION ...
```

But this isn't a very good solution if the paths are say of length 200, and I'm worried about the performance of using many Unions.

I have created a Neo4j Gist here with the sample data:
http://gist.neo4j.org/?a8ab894c5c9740a94747

Sample Data

```
CREATE
// Destinations.
(d1:Destination {id:'A'}),
(d2:Destination {id:'B'}),
(d3:Destination {id:'C'}),
(d4:Destination {id:'D'}),
(d5:Destination {id:'E'}),
(d6:Destination {id:'F'}),
// First Route
(v1:Visit {time:1}),
(v2:Visit {time:2}),
(v3:Visit {time:3}),
(v4:Visit {time:4}),
(v5:Visit {time:5}),
(v1)-[:LOCATION]->(d1),
(v2)-[:LOCATION]->(d2),
(v3)-[:LOCATION]->(d3),
(v4)-[:LOCATION]->(d4),
(v5)-[:LOCATION]->(d6),
(v1)-[:NEXT]->(v2)-[:NEXT]->(v3)-[:NEXT]->(v4)-[:NEXT]->(v5),
// Second Route
(v6:Visit {time:10}),
(v7:Visit {time:21}),
(v8:Visit {time:23}),
(v10:Visit {time:45}),
(v6)-[:LOCATION]->(d1),
(v7)-[:LOCATION]->(d2),
(v8)-[:LOCATION]->(d4),
(v9)-[:LOCATION]->(d6),
(v10)-[:LOCATION]->(d5),
(v11)-[:LOCATION]->(d3),
(v6)-[:NEXT]->(v7)-[:NEXT]->(v8)-[:NEXT]->(v9)-[:NEXT]->(v10)-[:NEXT]->(v11);
```

Expected Output

```
Path    PathCount
[A, B]  2
[D, F]  1
[B, D]  1
[B, C]  1
[C, D]  1
[B, C, D]   1
[C, D, F]   1
[A, B, C]   1
[A, B, D]   1
... many more
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you? It returns the head of each path as `PathHead`, an ordered collection of all the other nodes in the path as `PathTail`, and the number of steps in the path as `PathCount`.

```
MATCH (d1:Destination)<-[:LOCATION]-(v1:Visit)-[:NEXT*]->(:Visit)-[:LOCATION]->(d2:Destination)
RETURN d1.id as PathHead, COLLECT(d2.id) AS PathTail, COUNT(*) AS PathCount
```

Comment: No sorry this query does not help. Only the first and last destination is included in each of the paths. Also, I wasn't clear in the question, I wanted the count of the paths that have the same Destinations not the length of a single path.

Comment: I believe my query does return all the destinations on the path. I verified it with your sample data, and I had edited my answer to show the results.

Are you saying that you actually want to know, for each Destination, how many paths contain it? Or do you want something else?

Comment: Your query only returns 4 rows, and one of them is of length 7, where the longest path in the sample data is length 6. I want to find the counts for the number of times a path (of any length) of Destinations is visited. I'm expecting (from the sample data) a result set of many paths from length 2-6 with a PathCount of at most 2 which would be for [A,B] which is the only common path between the 2 sample routes.